# How to run Javascript code on a large JSON file and get the output

Tags: javascript, json

I have a relatively large JSON file (~23mb) that I need to parse and edit via Javascript. (In other words, I need to actually run code on the Javascript object that the JSON represents, then have the new object converted back into a JSON file- not just edit it in a text editor.) I don't need to actually see the file rendered on screen (and I would prefer not to, for performance reasons). How do I do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Write a quick node.js program.

Comment: I was hoping for something that doesn't require a root-level installation.

Comment: Search for "install node ubuntu no sudo" or something. It's not hard.